# Flask-Sqlalchemy - How to combine query results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have 2 sqlalchemy models defined as:

```
class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    directories = db.relationship('Directory', secondary=pages_dirs_table, backref='pages')

class Directory(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'directories'

    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('directories.id'))
    children = db.relationship("Directory",
                           cascade="all",
                           backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side='Directory.id'),
                           collection_class=mapped_collection(lambda x: x.name.lower()))
```

I am trying to create a query to find all pages and directories that have a specific parent directory.  That is, for a specific X, any directory whose parent is X and any page whose directories contains X.

So the obvious solution is to form 2 separate queries, both of which individually work.

`Page.query.filter(Page.directories.contains(X)).all()`

AND

`Directory.query.filter(Directory.parent == X).all()`

But, I need to combine the results of these into 1 list with pagination. So ideally I'd like to combine them before the `.all()` step (which would be replaced by one `.limit().offset().all()`).

So my database knowledge is a bit limited, but I've tried the following:

`Page.query.join(Directory)`...

But this crashes with `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to <class 'site_editor.modules.pages.models.Directory'>, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'pages' and 'directories'.`)

Then I tried doing it via db.session and using multiple tables in the query... like `db.session.query(Page, Directory).filter(Directory.parent == X, Page.directories.contains(X))`. But that is querying tuples of (Page, Directory), which isn't very useful as I need one or the other, not both.

I think I'm just missing some core understanding of how to use database joins to create complicated queries...

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.